# PHP - Making Class Object Global Throughout Entire Application?

Tags: php, class, global

Is there a simple way to make a class object global for an entire application in PHP? I need my class to only be able to be instantiated once throughout the entire application and have it working 100%.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Decided the Singleton pattern is the best idea for what I need, and was requested to add a bit of code so here it is:

Using the class in my app:

```
function catp_check_request(){
    $catp=catp::getInstance();

    $dlinks=array();
    $ddlinks=array();

    foreach($catp->rawlinks->link as $rawlink){
        $dellink="catp-del-{$rawlink->name}";
        array_push($dlinks,$dellink);
    }

    // More stuff..
}
```

Declaring the class:

```
class catp {

private static $instance;
private $errors;
private $status_messages;
private $plugin_name;
private $plugin_shortname;
private $links;
private $linksurl;
private $rawlinks;

private function __construct(){}

public static function getInstance() {
    if (self::$instance == null) {
        self::$instance = new catp();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

public function catp(){
    $this->errors=false;
    $this->plugin_name='CloakandTrack Plugin';
    $this->plugin_shortname='CaTP';
    $this->status_messages=array(
        'updated' => 'You just updated',
        'enabled' => 'You just enabled',
        'disabled' => 'You just disabled',
        'debug' => 'Plugin is in debug mode'
    );
    $this->linksurl=dirname(__FILE__).'/links.xml';
    $this->rawlinks=simplexml_load_file($this->linksurl);
    $this->links=$this->catp_parse_links($this->rawlinks);
}

// More functions..

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need singleton object.

```
class YourClass { 
    private $_instance = null;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$_instance == null) {
            self::$_instance = new YourClass();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}

// to get your instance use
YourClass::getInstance()->...;
```

Check this link for more details http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php#language.oop5.patterns.singleton

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. I tried switching my code over to look similar to the link you provided me with, but now I am getting these kinds of errors: `Fatal error: Cannot access private property catp::$rawlinks in . . .` - Is this something that happens commonly? It seems each variable is actually returning `NULL`.

Comment: You need to make your variables in class public or write get method for each.
`public $rawlinks;` or `public function getRawlinks() { return $this->rawlinks; }`

Comment: Maybe you need to declare $_instance with `static`. I'm not a PHP guy, but in several other languages that I have used, instance variables cannot be accessed in static functions.

Answer (score 2):

See the [singleton pattern on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=singleton+[php]) (and in which cases it is considered bad practice).

You may consider also using [registry](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=registry+[php]).

Note that your problem might be an architectural one and maybe there are better ways to solve the problem you face, e.g. dependency injection container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use __autoload feature to include the class dynamically for you.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-autoload/

Comment: that doesn't instantiate it for him